# What uniformly replaces the StringIO of Python2 in Python3?

Tags: python, stringio, bytesio

The documentation suggests that `BytesIO` is the new `StringIO`, because it supports **current-relative seeks**.

However, this is **incorrect**.

`BytesIO` cannot be used uniformly with `TextIOWrappers` as they are returned by `open()` calls. The former returns **bytes** the later returns **text** objects when reading.

`TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(...))` also, does not do work as desired, because again, it does not support relative seeks.

So what is the best construct to replace the python2 `StringIO` in python3?

Comment: Dis you try `io.StringIO`? https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#stringio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single uniform replacement, as string handling itself has changed in Python 3.

The class for in-memory text files in Python 3 is `io.StringIO`. Like other text files, it doesn't support current-relative seeks. While `io.StringIO` could theoretically support efficient current-relative seeks, for consistency with other text files (and to avoid constraining the implementation), it refuses to do so.

The class for in-memory binary files in Python 3 is `io.BytesIO`. There's a good chance that this is what you should be using (and if it is, then you should probably be opening your disk files in binary mode too).

If you really need the flexibility of Python 2's `StringIO.StringIO.seek` handling with an in-memory text file in Python 3, your best bet may be to write your own class.

Comment: I guess, a ``Py2StringIO`` would be a good candidate for a class in ``io``. It could then be used automatically by the migration tool ``2to3``. String processing is the major pain during the migration,

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer: It'd never happen. Even if it wasn't far too late for something like that, such a class would be too much of an invitation for people to keep mixing up bytes and unicode.

Comment: Sad. That makes it difficult to do a smooth transition from 2 to 3.

Comment: Update: The whole things with cur-relative seeking, even with ``TextIOWrappers(...)`` becomes messy. I decided to rewrite my code entirely to not use cur-relative seeks. Then, the good old new ``StringIO`` does the job.